# Change page URL sent to Universal Google Analytics when using Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

How can I change the page URL that is sent to Universal Google Analytics when using Google Tag Manager? Without Google Tag Manager it's really simple. You just have to add `ga('set', 'page', '/my/custom/url');` before `ga('send', 'pageview');`.

Your Google Analytics script needs to be like this:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
      ga('set', 'page', '/my/custom/url'); /* Set my custom URL */
      ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

How can I do something similar using Google Tag Manager?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Changing the "dp" value can be accomplished in GTM by setting the desired value in the `page` field, under "Fields to set":

[image]

**Edit**: For dynamic page values, you could define them in the dataLayer (make sure it's defined BEFORE your GTM container snippet so that the pageview tag sees it):

```
dataLayer = [{
   'newPage': '/your/page/here'
}];
```

and define a Data Layer type variable that captures the `newPage` value, which you use as the value of the `page` field.

Comment: But I need to set a different URL value for every page.

Comment: Adding a dataLayer variable will do just this. Elegant, easy solution!

Comment: Thanks! Working just fine. Defined `window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; window.dataLayer.push({'customPagePath': '/my/custom/page/path'});` before GTM snippet. Then defined a new Data Layer Variable **Custom Page Path** for the data layer variable name **{{customPagePath}}** with the default value set to **{{Page Path}}**. That way Google Analytics will always work, with or without my customPagePath set. Finally changed the field **page** in Universal Analytics  tag configuration to **{{Custom Page Path}}**.

Comment: @jacbmelo: be aware that you may be loosing information for existing pages. Thats way i extended your approach with a custom javascript variabel **{{scriptedPagePath}}** which just returns `location.pathname+location.search+location.hash;` - which i then use as default value of **{{customPagePath}}**

Comment: @GeorgEngel, you don´t need this custom Javascript. When you define the **Custom Page Path** Data Layer Variable you can set its default value to the built in **{{Page Path}}** variable.

Answer (score 0):

While the existing answer is perfectly correct, a screen dump with some more context would have been helpful in finding the right settings section to expand. Especially when using the interface in a non-English language. The translations can sound a bit weird sometimes and it may not always be obvious where to click.

So, here is an example of Universal Analytics configuration with a custom "page" field set, with more context and with the current (fall 2019) user interface design.

[image: Page path configuration for Universal Analytics with context]

Also, a related tip is that if you set the custom page path through a variable, it is possible in the custom variable configuration for data layer variables to specify the built-in "Page Path" variable as a default value, in case the custom value might be missing from the data layer for some pages.

[image: Configuration of Page Path as the default for a custom variable used to set a custom path]